# Google amp-lightbox: content higher then screen, not possible to scroll to top

Tags: css, amp-html

I`m try to make google amp lightbox with a long text, not fitting ligntbox on some devices, using scrollable attribute in lightbox tag. Text is scrolling but its not possible to scroll to most top of text, top part is hidden.
Below html, css, and two images, one with text fit fine in lightbox, other one scrolled to top, but top of text is invisible.
Note: I don't know screen height, and custom javascript not allowed in amp, so I can't use iframe, or div with overflow as them require height.

Amp html part: {$law.text} replaced with long text

```
<amp-lightbox id="law-lightbox" layout="nodisplay" class="popup-lightbox" scrollable>
  <div class="popup-content">
    <div class="popup-content-header">
      <button type="button" on="tap:law-lightbox.close" class="popup-close">×</button>
      <h4 class="popup-header-title">{$law.title}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-content-body">
      {$law.text}  
    </div>    
  </div>
</amp-lightbox>
```

CSS:

```
.popup-lightbox{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.popup-content{
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  left:  50%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 420px;
}
.popup-content-body {
    background-image: url("/i/site-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: #E6D0BB;
    color: #603415;
    padding: 4px;
}
.popup-close{
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #E6D0BB;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: -4px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.popup-close:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
.popup-content-header {
  background-color: #603415;
    color: #E6D0BB;
    padding: 2px;
}
.popup-content-header h4 {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.popup-header-title {
}
.popup_field {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This image scrolled to top, but part of top text is hidden:
[image: brokenimage]

This is how it looks on bigger displays:
[image: big]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.popup-content{
      max-height:100%;
      overflow:auto;
   }`

That should help. You are never setting a height or max height and you are centering it so no matter how long it will be it will be centered... if you want to have it scrollable you need to set something like above. Max height to like 90% any you will have a little space from top and bottom :)

Comment: when amp-lightbox have scrollable attribute it can scroll without overflow in style, anyway your max-height solution working fine, thanks!